# Force refresh/load Named Ranges on Workbook Open in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of Named Ranges that are coming from our File Management system metadata. Usually on workbook open it takes some time (up to 5 seconds) to load these values to cells. I have some other processes linked to these cells. For example showing/hiding shapes if let's say cell A1 > 1. The problem is that now there is no code to identify are these values already loaded so that another code can be performed.

Question: Is there any way to force load Named Ranges values by VBA? Or ensure they are loaded?

This is how Name Manager looks like (all these ="" are filled with values on Workbook_Open):

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

On Error Resume Next

'Application.Visible = False

    Loading.LabelProgresso.Width = 0
    Loading.Show (vbModeless)

    oFractionComplete (0)

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN").ScrollArea = "$A$1:$BL$45"

    oFractionComplete (0.1)

    'ENSURE NAMED RANGES ARE LOADED (CODE HERE)

        DoEvents

            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Price calculation").Range("G1866") > 500000 And _
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("U7") = "value" Or _
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("T31") > 500000 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").Shapes("LimitRequest").Visible = True
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").Shapes("CreditCheck").Visible = False
            Else
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").Shapes("LimitRequest").Visible = False
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").Shapes("CreditCheck").Visible = True
            End If

    oFractionComplete (0.2)
    ........
```

Comment: I am not sure about the technical details of your question, but it would certainly be easy to test if the ranges are loaded: `Dim n As Name, c As Range` : `For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names` : takes you into every named range : `For Each c In n.RefersToRange` : takes you through every cell.  It may not be fast, it may not be elegant, but it settles the question about unloaded ranges.  You could try looking at the first and last indexes, it would certainly be faster ... But if `ThisWorkbook.Names(1000)` loads, I have no idea if that also means 1-999 are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating a named range for your range of named ranges, then counting the blanks, zeros and errors, then use the results to create your condition for proceeding on to other procedures.

```
Sub CreateNRandCountBlank()

'~~~> Assign the data types for the variables.
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strNamedRange As String
Dim rngNamedRange As Range
Dim iBlanks As Long
Dim iZeros As Long
Dim iErrors As Long
Dim rngErrors As Range


'~~~> Assign objects to variables.
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

'~~~> Name of the named range to be created.
strNamedRange = "RangeOfNR"

'~~~> The worksheet that contains the range.
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Named Ranges")

'~~~> Assign a range of cells to the named range.
Set rngNamedRange = ws.Range("A1:A100")

'~~~> If the specified named range currently exist...
If RangeNameExists(strNamedRange) = True Then

    '~~~> Delete it.
    wb.Names(strNamedRange).Delete

End If

    '~~~> Create the specified named range.
    wb.Names.Add Name:=strNamedRange, RefersTo:=rngNamedRange

    '~~~> Count the cells in the range that have blank values.
    iBlanks = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range(strNamedRange))
    Debug.Print "iBlanks " & iBlanks

    '~~~> Count the cells in the range that have values equal to 0.
    iZeros = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(strNamedRange), 0)
    Debug.Print "iZeros " & iZeros

    '~~~> Count the cells in the range that contain errors.
    On Error Resume Next

    Set rngErrors = ws.Range(strNamedRange).SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rngErrors Is Nothing Then

        iErrors = rngErrors.Cells.Count

    Else

        iErrors = 0

    End If

    Debug.Print "iErrors " & iErrors

    '~~~> Action goes here.
    MsgBox _
        iBlanks & " Blanks" & vbNewLine & _
        iZeros & " Zeros" & vbNewLine & _
        iErrors & " Errors", vbOKOnly, "Range Analysis"

'~~~> Release the variables from memory.
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set rngNamedRange = Nothing
Set rngErrors = Nothing
iBlanks = vbNull
iZeros = vbNull
iErrors = vbNull
strNamedRange = vbNullString

End Sub


Private Function RangeNameExists(rngName) As Boolean

Dim n As Name

    RangeNameExists = False

    For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names

        If UCase(n.Name) = UCase(rngName) Then

            RangeNameExists = True

            Exit Function

        End If

    Next n

End Function
```